# Add Custom Attribute Text In PDF Invoice after Product Name in Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.4, invoice

How to i can add attribute text in pdf invoice after product name in Magento 2.4.0 ?

I am writing this code but not effecting.

```
$id = $item->getProductid();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);
$preorder =   $product->getAttributeText('preorder');

 if($preorder == "Yes") {
   $lines[][] = [
   'text' => $this->string->split('Pre Order', 10, true, true),
   'feed' => 125,
   'height' => 0,
    ];
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code like below. Please add your attribute value in below code.

```
$attributeVal = 1;

if($attributeVal == 1) {
    $lines[][] = [
        'text' => $this->string->split('Custom Attribute Value', 40, true, true),
        'feed' => 35,
    ];
}
```

Output :- https://prnt.sc/1qfmrpv

**Cheers!**

Comment: Yes we can apply condition

Comment: I have updated my answer with condition

Comment: If it is useful for you then please upvote and approve so other members can use it :)

Comment: I have updated my code, can we reduced this gap (height) between attribute and product name ? If yes please share that code (piece of line.) Thanks

Comment: Yes , i will share in few minutes

Comment: any help on reducing height space between product name attribute? actually pdf css is giving me challenge ... so that's why i am stuck on that.